# How do I override virtual method with parameter that inherits base method parameter?

Tags: c#, inheritance, virtual-functions, overriding

I have a set of objects inherited from `ObjBase` class. Processing logic is pretty same for all of these objects with a little differences. How do I keep all logic in `public virtual void Work(ObjBase o)` and process specific logic in overridden methods.

Example below is something I want to achieve, but it can't compile because of overriding parameters.

What be the better way to implement that ?

```
class Foo
{
    public void Do(ObjBase o)
    {
        switch (o.RequestType)
        { 
            case "A":
                new ProcA<ObjA>().Work(o);
                break;
            case "B":
                new ProcB<ObjB>().Work(o);
                break;
        }
    }
}

class ObjBase { }
class ObjA : ObjBase { }
class ObjB : ObjBase { }

class ProcBase
{
    public virtual void Work(ObjBase o)
    {
        //Common things to do...
    }
}

class ProcA<T> : ProcBase where T : ObjBase
{
    public override void Work(ObjA o)
    {
        base.Work(o);
        //DoSpecificWork
    }
}

class ProcB<T> : ProcBase where T : ObjBase
{
    public override void Work(ObjB o)
    {
        base.Work(o);
        //DoSpecificWork
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you can't. I would advise that you put the custom code in the `virtual` method (i.e. also add an `override`), and cast - for example:

```
public override void Work(ObjBase o)
{
    base.Work(o);
    var a = o as ObjA;
    if (a != null)
    {
        // do a-specific things
    }
}
```

This ensures that your logic happens even if they call the base-type's method.

You could *also* provide a new overload, for example:

```
public void Work(ObjA o)
{
    Work((ObjBase)o);
}
```

But it is unclear that this adds much value.